# How to use the John Resig JavaScript Micro-Templating engine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, template-engine

I have searched for a bit on a basic example on using the [John Resig JavaScript Micro-Templating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) engine on Google but came out dry.

I decided to bring it to base guys. Can anyone help with a simple example on using this engine? I have never used a client side template engine before.

Update: This is the complete HTML document. Thanks to Will.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>John Resig JavaScript Micro-Templating engine</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="MicroTemplates.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Data
        var data = { fname: "fred" };

        function onloadFunction() {
            var s = $("#biodata").html();
            var s1 = tmpl(s, data);

            $("#target").html(s1);
        }
    </script>
    <script id="biodata" type="text/html">
        <div><%= fname %></div> 
    </script> 
</head>
<body onload="onloadFunction();">
    <div id="target">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a link to a Fiddle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The link you provided has an example immediately after the engine code.  Read from the 2nd paragraph down.

CB, using your example, here is my take on the engine, which outputs the value of fname between div tags. To carry out the generation you would do something like:

```
var data = { fname : "fred" };
var generatedText = tmpl("biodata", data);
```

Then you'd have to output it, eg.

```
document.write(generatedText);
```

Or (assuming a div exists in the page with the id of 'elemId')

```
var elem = document.getElementById("elemId");
elem.innerHTML = generatedText;
```

All the above is untested, but hopefully accurate. Hope it helps!

Comment: Excellent, my first accepted answer!  Glad to have been of help! =)