# How to use microtemplate

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-templates

For some reason, I can't get the [John Resig micro template](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) to work. I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1775085/1252748), and can get this example to work, but it is for a very simple object.(ie. `var data = { fname : "fred" };`), however, when I try to use my more complicated object

```
{"order":{"name":"TRADEMARK WHEEL COMPANY","sales_order_id":"18278","order_date":"05 \u2044 15 \u2044 2012","due_date":"05 \u2044 21 \u2044 2012","order_number":"1213140","reference":"21192D\/35546","order_description":"BICICLETTE","ship_name":"ADAMS","ship_address1":"1919 W RANDOLPH ST.","ship_address2":"","ship_city":"CHICAGO","ship_state":"IL","ship_postal_code":"60606","ship_country":null,"ship_via":"FEDEX GROUND","tracking_number":null,"package_contents":null,"freight":"0.00","taxable":"0.00","nontaxable":"748.88","sales_tax":"0.00"},"line_item":[{"description":"RED ONE","quantity":"2.00","sell_price":"349.44"},{"description":"FRONT GEAR","quantity":"2.00","sell_price":"15.00"},{"description":"5th GEAR","quantity":"2.00","sell_price":"10.00"}]}
```

and try to access it like so

```
<script>
(function () {

  var submitStr="test string of data";

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getJSON.php",
    data: submitStr,
    success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    var generatedText = tmpl("order_detail", data);
    var elem = document.getElementById("elemId");
    elem.innerHTML = generatedText;
    }
    });

}());
</script>
<script id="order_detail" type="text/html">
        <div>
Name:<%=data.order.name%> ID:<%=data.order.sales_order_id%><hr/>

<%for(var i=0;i<data.line_item.length;i++) {%>

      description: <%= data.line_item[i].description %><br/>
      quantity: <%= data.line_item[i].quantity %><br/>
      price: <%= data.line_item[i].sell_price %><hr/>


<%}%>
</div> 

 </script>
```

I get the error that `data` is undefined. I've tried it without `data.`, simply trying to access the object's values directly, but that doesn't work either.

I'm grateful for any help using this thing!

Comment: what do you get with `console.log(data);`

Comment: i get the object printed out like a json string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.In `$.ajax` success callback `success: function (data)` you get the `data` as a JSON string, you have to parse it to an object before pass it to the `tmpl` function.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getJSON.php",
    data: submitStr,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);

        data = JSON.parse(data);

        var generatedText = tmpl("order_detail", data);
        var elem = document.getElementById("elemId");
        elem.innerHTML = generatedText;
    }
});
```

2.remove all the `data` prefix in your template.

Comment: `console.log(data) //{"order":{"name":"TRADEMARK WHEEL COMPANY","sales_order_id":"18278","order_date":"05 \u2044 15 \u2044 2012","due_date":"05 \u2044 21 \u2044 2012","order_number":"1213140","reference":"21192D\/35546","order_description":"BICICLETTE","ship_name":"ADAMS","ship_address1":"1919 W RANDOLPH ST.","ship_address2":"","ship_city":"CHICAGO","ship_state":"IL","ship_postal_code":"60606","ship_country":null,"ship_via":"FEDEX`

Comment: `GROUND","tracking_number":null,"package_contents":null,"freight":"0.00","taxable":"0.00","nontaxable":"748.88","sales_tax":"0.00"},"line_item":[{"description":"RED ONE","quantity":"2.00","sell_price":"349.44"},{"description":"FRONT GEAR","quantity":"2.00","sell_price":"15.00"},{"description":"5th GEAR","quantity":"2.00","sell_price":"10.00"}]}` and the error is still there `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined`

Comment: @thomas that's what Chrome would log when `data` is a string, if it's an object, chrome would display `Object` with an arrow. I've updated my answer for the second point.

Comment: using [this function] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3826081) `console.log(data)` gives me [object Object]

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks you so much. I honestly had tried parsing with jquery parsejson, but must've erred somewhere critical. You saved my head many concussions and my desk many dents. Thank you so much!!